# Is paralellizability a topological invariant (Invariant under homemorphism)

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

[This  MO  post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58131/parallelizability-of-the-milnors-exotic-spheres-in-dimension-7)  is  a  motivation to  ask:

> Is paralellizability  a  topological invariant (Invariant under homeomorphism)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. You can cook up counterexamples in high dimensions via surgery theory. The relevant paper here is Milnor, "Microbundles and differentiable structures", available [here](http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/notes/milnor4.pdf). The theorem you want is Corollary 6.4; as a corollary of this, Milnor gives an example of a (noncompact) smooth parallelizable manifold that carries a different, non-parallelizable differentiable structure.

You should be able to find closed examples using this corollary, but I don't know any off the top of my head.

Comment: thank you for your very helpful  answer.